# Contour integration over a positively oriented circle |z| = 1

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have the following integrals to integrate where the contour is the positively oriented circle $|z| = 1$

$$ \int {e^z \over z^2(z-i)} dz$$
$$ \int {\sin z \over z(z^2+2)} dz$$
$$ \int {\cosh z \over z^3} dz$$

I have been working on contour integrals for quite a while now and am having a very hard time wrapping my head around them. I have tried to work out the first integral using the Cauchy Integral Theorem and the second using the Deformation Invariance Theorem but I am still having trouble working through them. Any hints or ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The second integral may be evaluated using Cauchy's integral formula. The numerator is an entire function and the only pole that is in the interior of C is z = 0. Then complete with Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: In the first integral you have a pole *in* the integration path.

Comment: @Simon, isn't a pole, is removable.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Can you elaborate? I'm certain that the poles are $z = 0, z = \pm j\sqrt{2}$ and the last two poles are not on or in the interior of the curve. Therefore, you can just deform the curve so that it's a tiny circle of radius $\epsilon > 0$ near $z = 0$. Then, proceed using Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Comment: @Simon, $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}z = 1$.